# Android MediaMetadataRetriever setDataSource failed

Tags: android, video, media

I'm trying to use Android `MediaMetadataRetriever` to get the length of recorded videos in mp4 format - but I'm getting the exception:

```
07-13 13:54:32.686: E/AndroidRuntime(19790): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-13 13:54:32.686: E/AndroidRuntime(19790): java.lang.RuntimeException: setDataSource failed: status = 0x80000000
```

My code is:

```
MediaMetadataRetriever retriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
            retriever.setDataSource(video.getMediaUrl());
            String time = retriever.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_DURATION);
            long timeInmillisec = Long.parseLong(time);
```

And the `video.getMediaUrl()` path is similar to this:

```
file:///storage/emulated/0/Foldername/Videos/VID_20130713_135318.mp4
```

I don't know what i am doing wrong - anyone help me out, please! Also this code works fine for Audio Files, but not for videos.

Comment: MediaMetadataRetriever is probably just unable to read that particular video file for whatever reason. Have you tried https://github.com/wseemann/FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever?

Comment: it can't read every file i'm giving to him recorded from my camera.... so no - didnt test the library but maybe will test it later - thanks in advance

Comment: What I'm saying is, the issue might be related to the codec the camera is using or how it's writing out metadata. Also, can you post a sample file?

Comment: I'm just trying to read files being recorded from my own camera - starting the camera via:
        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);

        Uri fileUri = CameraFileHelper.getOutputMediaFileUri(CameraFileHelper.MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO);
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);

        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY, VIDEO_QUALITY_HIGH);

Answer (score 11):

```
public static String getFileDuration(Context context, File file) {
    String result = null;
    MediaMetadataRetriever retriever = null;
    FileInputStream inputStream = null;

    try {
        retriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
        inputStream = new FileInputStream(file.getAbsolutePath());
        retriever.setDataSource(inputStream.getFD());
        long time = Long.parseLong(retriever.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_DURATION));
        result = String.format(context.getResources().getString(R.string.player_time_format),
        AppUtil.getPlayerMinutes(time), AppUtil.getPlayerSoconds(time));

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (RuntimeException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally{
       if (retriever != null){
           retriever.release()
       }if (inputStream != null){
           inputStream.close()
       }
    }  
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Always release retriever and close inputstream once done with it.

Comment: Save my day. tnx +1

Answer (score 4):

Remove **file://** from video URI before passing it to **setDataSource** method.

Comment: can you add some explanation?

Answer (score 0):

FileInputStream works for me.

`String path = "somepath";
java.io.FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream(path);
mediaMetadataRetriever.setDataSource(input.getFD());`

Comment: Write some explanation to make understand your answer.

Answer (score -1):

[Kirill F.'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32747923) helped me fix this error.

```
path = path.substring(7);
mmr.setDataSource(path);
```